# Setup old MSYS2 environment

Tags: msys2

I need to cross-compile an old application using mingw64 on MSYS2 (on Windows 10). The application compiles only with an old version of gcc (should be 5.2.0) and other packages (the application compiles on ubuntu 16.04).

Can I setup an old MSYS2 environment? How is the MSYS2 installation related to the packages, i.e. can install old packages (assuming I can find them) on a new MSYS2 installation?

Comment: MSYS2 doesn't have a built-in way of installing old package versions. You can manually download and install them from [the repos](https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/mingw64/), but the oldest GCC in the repos is 10.x. Your best bet is downloading a compiler manually from elsewhere, and only use MSYS2 as a shell if you need it.

Comment: Is there any way I can cross-compile using other tools (e.g. Cygwin)? I would still need a legacy environment.

Comment: You don't really need other tools. Download the compiler from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/postdownload) and use it. If you need Bash and so on, use MSYS2 and add that compiler to PATH.